# What are the fields needed to check for SQLI, XSS, XSRF and Remote file inclusion attacks in apache access log file

Tags: network, appsec, botnet

I need to identify the SQLI, DoS, XSS attacks from log file. At which field  these attacks will reflect in log file. Please suggest me some idea and send  materials to me.

Comment: Check this post, it looks very close to yours:
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117/can-i-detect-web-app-attacks-by-viewing-my-apache-log-file

Comment: K. Thanks sir. I want to know Which feature i have to choose for XSS, SQLI attacks.